# How to Fix CORS Error in Angular for Bigcommerce API

Tags: angular, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to connect a very simple Angular 10 app to the Bigcommerce API and I get the following error:

Access to fetch at 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/0r5ke/v3/products' from origin 'https://angular-example123.stackblitz.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am using stackblitz.io since it provides the https connection Bigcommerce requires. So I have my app.component.ts as follows:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from './product';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  url ='https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/0rfgr/v3/products';
  products: Observable<any>;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

  getProducts() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('X-Auth-Token', '123456789').set('X-Auth-Client', '123456789').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    this.products = this.http.get(this.url, { headers })
  }
}
```

product.ts file:

```
export interface Product {
  name: string;
}
```

If I change the URL to "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" it works and the data gets displayed. Any help on why it's not working with Bigcommerce will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment - you should not put your Auth Headers in Client-Side code - do not embed them in JS running from a browser. An attacker can read them and use it to attack your store's API. 
Create a serverside application and embed the credentials as environment variables.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip. After researching, I found out that Bigcommerce does not allow CORS. I have to install and authorize the Angular app within the Bigcommerce store. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to do that, you just need to create a node/backend server to proxy the API requests to BC, and send your front-end the data - you configure your backend to allow cors - either to certain domains, or allow all cors.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend api should be allowing CORS connection. Only then you can access the data from the client. Its not related to the Angular code, but the api itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: If I place the URL and headers on Postman it works perfectly. Is there a workaround about this that you know of?

Comment: It will work in Postman as it is calling from Node.js not client side browser code. You can create a Node.js application which relays the api. That is basically you can call your api which calls the Bigcommerce API. Make sure your Node.js application has CORS enabled apis.